# Proving that an open interval is an open set

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that a,b exist in $\Bbb R$ with $a < b$.  Show for every $x$ that exists in $(a,b)$, there exists $\epsilon\ > 0$ such that there is an $\epsilon$-neighborhood centered at $x$ that is contained in $(a, b)$.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: *Cough* Density of rationals *Cough*

Comment: Density of the rationals has nothing to do with it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: draw a picture.

As long as $\epsilon$ is shorter than both the distance from $x$ to $a$ and the distance from $x$ to $b$, you have what you want. (See?)

Comment: I drew a picture and I was working off of what @copper.hat had written above because a proof somewhat similar to this was discussed in class.  My problem is I'm confused on how to prove this existence of the defined epsilon for every x in the interval.

Comment: @Student copper.hat gave away exactly what my hint was getting at. Since the distance between $x$ and either of $a$ or $b$ always exists, this is certainly the way to go, no?

Comment: So for my proof:
Suppose some a,b in the reals such that a<b.
Consider some epsilon>0 and x in the interval (a, b) such that (x-a)<epsilon.  Thus, x<epsilon+a.  But x is in the interval (a, b), so this cannot be the case.  And prove the same for b-x?

Comment: @Student No, there is no "let $\epsilon>0$". You need to *chose* epsilon. After wisely choosing, you point out why you can move above $x$ and below $x$ by epsilon without escaping the interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: Ok thanks. That makes sense

Answer (score 2):

If $x\in (a,b)$, then take $\epsilon = \min(b-x,x-a)$.